# multicast bind interface issue

Tags: boost, multicast

I have an issue which I am confused.
for example, if I want to join a multicast group 239.255.0.1:30001 to receive data. which interface should I bind to? I saw some people say to bind to that multicast address 239.255.0.1:30001. how about binding to the local machine interface such as eth0/eth1?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the OS you're targetting.

- For Windows, bind to the local machine interface
- For Linux & Mac/iOS (and possibly other users of BSD-style sockets), bind to the multicast address
- For code that'll sort of work across both Windows & Linux, bind to INADDR_ANY (0).  Note that you might then have to filter out unwanted traffic.  Also, this won't work on Mac/iOS.

Comment: thank you. since I am using Linux, I would like know why to bind to the multicast address instead of local machine interface?

Comment: @MichaelD I'm not sure why the API behaves in this way.
You do need to use the interface address elsewhere - for the IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP (and optionally IP_MULTICAST_IF) sockopts.